# Interpretation of the SAS code meaning

Tags: sas

Please, help me to interpret the SAS code (I am quite new to sas):

```
DATA sample;

 SET sample;

   v_eq = mve;

   est_v_eq = v_eq;


   sig_eq = sige;



   WHERE optosey > 0 AND

    optprcey > 0; 

RUN;
```

Interpretation: Use "sample" - database. Define "v_eq = mve", "est_v_eq = v_eq", "sig_eq = sige" only for observations that have optosey > 0 AND optprcey > 0, am I right? What is confusing is that why do "they" define "v_eq = mve", "est_v_eq = v_eq" and not directly "v_eq = mve" ?

Comment: FYI, I'm considering this on-topic here and not [codereview.se] since this is a question about how the code works, not about improving the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpretation is broadly right.  Your question is a question I'd ask, also.  I would say that it depends on the purpose of this code; it's possible that this is written this way for readability; if you were saying the purpose of this code in English, perhaps that's how you'd describe it.

I'd warn that this is fairly bad form, though, in particular this part:

```
data sample;
  set sample;
  where ... ;
```

Normally when you are doing something irreversible, it is best to not write to the same dataset that you're reading from (since you're losing data).  `WHERE` does not only apply the above transformations; it actually filters the rows coming in, so only rows that qualify for the `WHERE` end up in the output dataset.